# Why the function is not returning

Tags: javascript

Why whenever i click the Button the x is not changed so i need some help

```
var x = 0;
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    x = 1;
    return x;
})
if(x == 1){
    alert("Hey")
}
```

Comment: Put more code. And why everybody is using "querySelector"? This is the new COVID, spreading everywhere!

Comment: @djcaesar9114 so how to fix it

Comment: Show us your complete code.

Comment: This the complete javascript code and in the html there is only this   <button id="btn">Click</button> in the body

Comment: The `if()` only runs once on page load and therefore will never be true

Comment: So what is the solution

Answer (score 0):

This is a scope issue. The value of `x` inside the functions scope is set to 1, however outside the scope its value is set to 0. So any code set inside the event handlers function will be set to the newly declared value inside the scope of the function.

If you need to display that value on the page, simply set the display code inside the scope of the function, not outside.

See my example... The value of x is set before the button event. It is set to the outer scopes value, we reset that value within the event handlers scope and then display that value on the page within the scope to set it to the desired value. However, looking at the console.log of x we can see the value of x is still set to 0 outside the scope of the event handler.

```js
var x = 0;
var displayTxt = document.getElementById("display");
displayTxt.textContent = x;
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  x = 1;
  console.log("scope of 'x' inside the function: " + x)
  if (x === 1) {
    alert("Hey, the scope of x inside the function is set to: " + x)
  }
  displayTxt.textContent=x;
  return x;
})
  console.log("scope of 'x' outside the function: " + x)
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Press Me">
<p>The value of x is currently set to: <span id="display"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about moving the if statement inside the click event?

```
var x = 0;
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    x = 1;
    if(x == 1){
        alert("Hey");
        }
});
```